# Get-History PowerShell doesn't work from PowerShell executed by C#

Tags: c#, powershell

When I call a PowerShell script from a Windows Forms program the function Get-History doesn't save the information.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
     {
           ps.Commands.AddScript(string.Format(@"Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass;set-location {0};.\{1}", Environment.CurrentDirectory, "fey.ps1"));
           ps.Invoke();
     }
}
```

PowerShell fey.ps1:

```
write 'a'
write 'b'
write 'c'

Get-History | Add-Content 'history.txt'
```

The file `history.txt` is empty.

Running on a PowerShell ISE instance it works properly.

Comment: `Get-History` gives the history of console commands. If you execute the script directly in the ISE, every individual line will be treated as console input, but `AddScript` does not do anything with the console. I know of no way to log individual script lines that aren't invoked interactively. PowerShell 5 includes auditing, but that seems overkill.

Comment: Ugh. Exact same question. I debug scripts by running them on the console and then it turns out they run totally differently when invoked properly (i.e., Get-History is useless).